# Type.GetType returning null when Assembly is dynamically loaded in AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, dynamic-loading, assembly-loading

I have assembly named `MyAssembly.dll` which is loaded dynamically using

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(@"path_to_MyAssembly_dll");
```

I want to get the `Type` from string(class name as string) which is present in `MyAssembly`, but is shows inconsistent behavior.

Sometime is gives correct Type(Class Type) which I wanted, and sometime it gives `null`

When the Type is null,I have checked assemblies in `AppDomain` using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

It shows `MyAssembly` loaded in AppDomain.

I am not getting why this is happening.

Comment: just to clarify the question - does that inconsistent behavior happens for one type or it happens consistently for different types?

Comment: @mihail It shows inconsistent behavior for different types.

Comment: so, you always get successfully type A but you are never able to get type B?

Comment: @mihail sorry for creating confusion. It shows inconsistent behavior for all types.